# which is the correct way to do a git remote

Tags: git, github, repository

i would need to understand what makes this code:

```
git remote add github -m master https://github.com/thesteve0/geoserver-on-openshift.git

git pull -s recursive -X theirs github master

git push origin
```

I run the code but i have this error:

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

I'm running git 1.9.1

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try typing git remote to see what remotes are set.... github shows the below as the way to add a repo.  My guess is that in order to push the remote origin, you actually need to  name it origin?

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
# Set a new remote

git remote -v
# Verify new remote
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)
```

Comment: Hi user3157191, when i run git remote it's give me back github, so i will try running what you say and i will comment how it's goes.